# Building PostgreSQL driver for Qt

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql, qt5, qmake

I trying to build psql driver but have some unexpected messages.

> maxim@maxim-VirtualBox:~/Downloads/distrib/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql$ qmake psql.pro
>
> Cannot read
>   /home/maxim/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1/qtbase/mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_lib_bootstrap_private.pri:
>   No such file or directory
>
> ...
>
> Cannot read
>   /home/maxim/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1/qtbase/mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_lib_xml_private.pri:
>   No such file or directory

But all of these files exist. What is the problem?

Comment: I am not sure if it can cause such issues, but you have not used qmake [as per documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#qpsql).

Comment: Also, have you tried to configure it like [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/sql-driver.html#building-the-drivers-using-configure)?

Comment: PostgreSQL installed in my home folder ~/install/PostgreSQL
I added into psql.pro:
INCLUDEPATH += /home/maxim/install/PostgreSQL-9.1.11/include
LIBS += -L/home/maxim/install/PostgreSQL-9.1.11/lib -lpq

Comment: And I am not interested in adding drivers during assembly qt-libraries. I need to install a plugin after qt-library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you have "modules-inst" as the subfolder name, whereas it is only "modules" without the "-inst" suffix in reality.

See how it works fine on my end:

> lpapp ~/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql $ qmake psql.pro
>
> lpapp ~/Downloads/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.2.1/qtbase/src/plugins/sqldrivers/psql $

Answer (score 0):

I found a problem. After install qt-libraries I created new folder 'distrib' and move sources in there. That's why I got this problem.
I should have checked the existence of the directory by cd command.